# Remove previously installed phones from Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, mobile-phone

Any ideas on how to remove these two Nokia phones from Windows Explorer ?

[image]

They've been removes from **Devices and Printers** and system has been rebooted since then.

Thank you.

Comment: What options, if any, do you see when you right-click those phone entries?

Comment: I do have 'Create Shortcut' and that's it.

Comment: If you installed PC Suite or some other Nokia bloatware, see if there's any option to hide disconnected phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're gone, another mystery of the computing world :-)

The only things I remember doing since then were :

- MSCONFIG -> normal startup
- CCleaner
- Plug my HTC again

Oh and yes, I removed that WDCOMM Generic Bluetooth software

I can hardly tell when they disappeared, I've just seen it right now ...